# Where Statement issue with SOQL, after upgrade

Tags: apex, soql, controller, custom

Not sure what happened but I had the following Custom Controller working just great until recently.  Not sure if it was the recent release or if I just completely missed the fact that it wasn't working right.

The issue is I have to filter the results of a query based on the created date of both notes and attachments which are related to the records pulled as well as the created date of the records themselves.  Right now, the only filter that is working is related to the records. The others do not seem to be working.

I put ** around the code that is not working.  Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

CUSTOM CONTROLLER

```
public class CasesandSubjectsController{
    public task taskRec{get; set;}
    public task taskRec1{get; set;}
    Set<Id> attachmentParentIds = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> notesId = new Set<Id>();
    public CasesandSubjectsController(ApexPages.StandardController sc){
        taskRec= new task (ActivityDateTime__c = Datetime.now().addMonths(-1));
        taskRec1= new task (ActivityDateTime__c = Datetime.now());
    }
    public Sec_Cases__c[] ca {
        get {
                Attachment[] attachments = [SELECT ParentId, CreatedDate FROM Attachment
                                        WHERE CreatedDate >= :taskRec.ActivityDateTime__c
                                        AND CreatedDate <= :taskRec1.ActivityDateTime__c];
                Note__c[] notes = [SELECT Id, CreatedDate, NotesCase__c FROM Note__c
                                        WHERE CreatedDate >= :taskRec.ActivityDateTime__c
                                        AND CreatedDate <= :taskRec1.ActivityDateTime__c];
                Sec_Cases__c[] cases = [SELECT Id, Name, Action_Taken__c, CreatedDate, LastModifiedDate, Case_Name__c, Case_Status__c, Case_Type__c, Summary__c, Report_StartDate__c, Report_EndDate__c, 
                            (SELECT Subject_Name__r.Id, Subject_Name__r.name, Subject_Name__r.Subject_Type__c FROM Subject_for_Cases__r), 
                            (SELECT name, Body__c, LastModifiedDate, CreatedDate FROM Notes__r
                                    WHERE CreatedDate >= :taskRec.ActivityDateTime__c
                                    AND CreatedDate <= :taskRec1.ActivityDateTime__c
                                    ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC), 
                            (SELECT CreatedDate, Id, name, ParentId FROM Attachments
                                    WHERE CreatedDate >= :taskRec.ActivityDateTime__c
                                    AND CreatedDate <= :taskRec1.ActivityDateTime__c                                    
                                    ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC)
                    FROM Sec_Cases__c
                        WHERE Case_Status__c = 'Active' AND
                            (**(Id IN :notesId)
                                  OR
                             (Id IN :attachmentParentIds)**
                                  OR
                             (CreatedDate >= :taskRec.ActivityDateTime__c 
                              AND CreatedDate <= :taskRec1.ActivityDateTime__c))
                        ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC ];

                return cases;
            }
    }
    public PageReference next(){
        PageReference nextpage = new PageReference('/apex/securityreport1ppv');
        return nextpage;
    }
    public PageReference next1(){
        PageReference nextpage = new PageReference('/apex/securityreport1sap');
        return nextpage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, these two lines here show the creation of two empty sets:

```
Set<Id> attachmentParentIds = new Set<Id>();
Set<Id> notesId = new Set<Id>();
```

You then have some code that queries attachments and notes:

```
Attachment[] attachments = [SELECT ParentId, CreatedDate FROM Attachment
                            WHERE CreatedDate >= :taskRec.ActivityDateTime__c
                            AND CreatedDate <= :taskRec1.ActivityDateTime__c];
Note__c[] notes = [SELECT Id, CreatedDate, NotesCase__c FROM Note__c
                            WHERE CreatedDate >= :taskRec.ActivityDateTime__c
                            AND CreatedDate <= :taskRec1.ActivityDateTime__c];
```

But then there is nothing getting the Ids and the attachment.

Then you try to use the empty sets here where you point out the non-working code:

```
  WHERE Case_Status__c = 'Active' AND
     ((Id IN :notesId)
        OR
     (Id IN :attachmentParentIds)
        OR
```

So your code is missing the bit that puts the values in `notesIds` and `attachmentParentIds`

For instance you would need to do something like

```
for (Attachment att : attachments){
    attachmentParentIds.add(att.ParentId);
}
```

and

```
for (Note__c note: notes){
    notesId.add(note.NotesCase__c); //I think this is the right one, but I'm guessing here.
```

Each of these would go after their respective query.

The bigger question is why did they stop working? You might want to look into the Setup Audit Trail for entries around when it stopped working to see if there have been any modifications to that class around then.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that.  Thanks so much!  That indeed fixed the issue and I am back in business.  :)